# default instancing of a class within the same class in C#

Tags: c#, class, default

So I want to have a compile time default instance of a class to reduce unneeded code

so:

```
public class Foo{
    public T Prop1
    public T Prop2

    public Foo(T prop1, T prop2){

    }

    public static Empty = ?
    //(I want this to be a Foo{Prop1=default1, Prop2=default2})
}
```

The benefit would be in multiple functions in many other classes where I want to have a default case (which needs to be there at compile time).

```
bar (T attri, Foo inFoo = Foo.Empty)
```

Comment: `Empty` can never be a compile time constant

Comment: @TimSchmelter It can be `null`.  It's a valid compile time constant for any reference type.  The only one for most.

Comment: @Servy: well, i should have said it can never be the desired `Empty` with the 2 default values.